# Caching Lifetime "Best Practice" for Google Pagespeed

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, google-pagespeed

im currently facing some problems while improving page speed of a customer website. Google says: There are several resources, which are not fitting with the perfect cache-lifetime. They are not providing any best practices for that, so which value is for which resource the best?

This is currently my htaccess part:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Google says: its better, but not good enough. So, is there anybody who can provide me some info or best practise for the perfect resource caching time? I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommends 1 year for static assets.

> We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and **preferably up to
> one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently**. If
> you need precise control over when resources are invalidated we
> recommend using a URL fingerprinting or versioning technique...
>
> Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

As stated you need to make sure you implement cache busting techniques to ensure you don't inadvertently serve old CSS etc.

It is calculated on a non linear scale (i.e. 6 months is not twice as good as 3 months) so it is not possible to give an exact numer of days but 6 months for all assets would pass, whereas all assets except CSS at 1 year with CSS at 1 week may not.

If you change your CSS and JS cache time to 1 year I would imagine this diagnostic would not show.

Always bear in mind these are recommendations and best practices, you have to do what is best for your site so ensure that any cache length you set is right for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! My score was not better, but google now says nothing anymore about it, so i think its fine now.

Comment: It doesn't change your score, sorry I think i confused you with the "score" being calculated on a sliding scale. The pass / fail on the diagnostic is based on a sliding scale. Scoring as in total score is not affected by anything under the "diagnostics" part of the report, it is there for things that may help improve performance.

Comment: okay, this info helps me much more. Thanks for catching up on this again. We changed the Server - so we have better bandwitdth and much more performance. Now the score jumps up, because the old server was "trash"